ID this scifi trilogy(?) about a teen boy who discovers a watch that can control time
I read this maybe three or years ago, paperback. I believe the first book's cover had Mars on it, and that the last book's cover had a spaceship and a lot of green on it.

I'm pretty sure the series was a trilogy. The first book took place mainly on Mars, I think (or at least that's where it started). The main characters are teenagers, probably around 16. I'm pretty sure only the first book took place on Mars.
On Mars, in the series, adults sometimes get "dust sickness" (I'm calling it that), where they get sick from the Mars dust. People born on Mars don't experience this problem. Children enjoy utilising the low gravity to do parkour/athletic activities such as jumping really high and jumping off the walls of buildings.
They live on Mars because their old home, Earth, had something bad happen to it that forced them to move (they were already on Mars at the beginning of the book, but this was an important part of the plot).
At some point early on in the first book, there's a man wearing some odd futuristic (even for them) space suit with a watch. He dies (I'm pretty sure) and the watch ends up with the main character (who's a teen boy). He's friends with a girl around the same age.
I don't remember when in the series any of the below takes place.
At some point, the two main characters (the boy and his friend) leave Mars on a small spaceship with just them. I don't remember why. Because they were traveling for a really long time, they went through cryostasis (or some kind of stasis, anyway) so they didn't have to experience the whole journey. They didn't age while they did this. There was an onboard ship AI navigator that helped them and that they talked to while not in stasis.
At some point, the kids play some video game on a console. The game was violent, of the co-op genre, and really hard, if I remember correctly. They were trying to beat their old record or something.
The boy eventually discovers the powers of the watch. He is able to use it to go forward and backward in time. I think it begins to have an adverse effect on him, but I don't remember what (it turns out fine though, I believe). He also tells his friend about it, and she plays around with it too. It's easier to use for the boy though, I think. Eventually, after the boy uses the watch a lot, he is able to use the powers of the watch without the watch.
They eventually find a really big ship with incredibly futuristic technology (even for them). The ship has its own on-board AI, and it is initially friendly. It turns out to be an enemy though, and tries to kill the boy and his friend somehow.
At some point, a 'lore bomb' is dropped and the boy discovers that humans from the future keep destroying stars by accelerating their lifespans to use for energy (I think). Something like that happened to Earth - the sun kept getting hotter and larger, and humans had to leave to survive. At the time, there was no risk on Mars, so it was safe to travel there. Eventually though, the problem kept getting worse and Mars could be in danger too.

Could it be the Chronicle of the Dark Star trilogy by Kevin Emerson from 2017?
From GoodReads:

It is Earth year 2213—but, of course, there is no Earth anymore. Not
since it was burned to a cinder by the sun, which has mysteriously
begun the process of going supernova. The human race has fled to Mars,
but this was only a temporary solution while we prepare for a second
trip: a one-hundred-fifty-year journey to a distant star, our best
guess at where we might find a new home.
Liam Saunders-Chang is one of the last humans left on Mars. The son of
two scientists who have been racing against time to create technology
vital to humanity’s survival, Liam, along with his friend Phoebe, will
be on the very last starliner to depart before Mars, like Earth before
it, is destroyed.
Or so he thinks. Because before this day is over, Liam and Phoebe will
make a series of profound discoveries about the nature of time and
space, and find out that the human race is just one of many in our
universe locked in a desperate struggle for survival.

From BookTalks:

The remains of the Earth fell into the sun years ago, and ever since
human beings have lived on Mars. Now Mars is about to suffer the same
fate, so its millions of inhabitants are being evacuated in giant
starliners, heading for a distant Earth-like planet, Aaru-5. Liam, his
friend Phoebe, and their parents have stayed behind until the last
minute, the parents completing terraforming trials for their new
planet, when a deadly explosion destroys the research station. The
starliner departs without them, leaving Liam, Phoebe, their
unconscious parents, and a panda-like robot named JEFF behind. Liam,
Phoebe, and JEFF set off to attempt a rendezvous with the starliner –
but in the meantime, they’ve discovered a dead blue alien with a
time-travel watch and met an intimidating representative of the
mysterious Drove, whose aim seems to be to destroy all of humanity.

The cover of the third book is green as described in the question:

