Book about humans evacuating Mars as the Sun is about to explode; heroes find a time travel watch
I read this book a long time ago. The book starts off with humans living on Mars, but massive spaceships are leaving every day to transport humans to planets far away as the Sun is nearing the end of its life. The Sun is sabotaged by a group of aliens, which causes it to explode earlier than predicted.
A girl from this alien group is sent with her family to infiltrate the humans, and befriends a human boy. They escape together from the Sun in a spaceship. They find out time travel somehow along the way with a watch, I do not clearly recall that part. They also find a spaceship that was part of a group that left Mars earlier but was lost in its travel, where they are captured by the aliens and the girl's identity is revealed.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

We did this one just last week.  This is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/292233/id-this-scifi-trilogy-about-a-teen-boy-who-discovers-a-watch-that-can-control/292235#292235

FWIW, IRL, the Sun is far too small to ever go supernova. Unless it happens to collide with a much larger star...

Having confirmed that Phoebe is secretly an alien, I'm pretty confident that this is the Chronicle of the Dark Star trilogy by Kevin Emerson; you probably read the first book Last Day on Mars.
The blurb for Last Day on Mars reads:

It is Earth year 2213—but, of course, there is no Earth anymore. Not since it was burned to a cinder by the sun, which has mysteriously begun the process of going supernova. The human race has fled to Mars, but this was only a temporary solution while we have prepared for a second trip: a one-hundred-fifty-year journey to a distant star, our best guess at where we might find a new home.
Liam Saunders-Chang is one of the last humans left on Mars. The son of two scientists who have been racing against time to create technology vital to humanity’s survival, Liam, along with his friend Phoebe, will be on the last starliner to depart before Mars, like Earth before it, is destroyed.
Or so he thinks. Because before this day is over, Liam and Phoebe will make a series of profound discoveries about the nature of time and space and find out that the human race is just one of many in our universe locked in a dangerous struggle for survival.

You can read more about the book on its Goodreads page or in this previous answer.  This review verifies that aliens have caused the Sun to start going supernova, the hero Liam and his friend Phoebe are among the last to be evacuated from Mars, Liam finds a time-travelling wristwatch.  Other reviews spoiler the fact that Phoebe is secretly an alien, and they go off on their own and find a giant (also secretly alien) ship.
